# Finding the average displacement of a particle on a fixed position of a mechanical wave for a period

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator

So, we know the average kinetic and potential energies are the same, and therefore we can express them as

$\left< W\right> = m\left< (\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})^{2}\right>$

We can develop the partial

$\left< W\right> = m\omega ^{2}A^{2}\left< sin^{2}(kx-\omega t)\right>$

But why, when finding the average displacement, do we find

$\frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} \frac{1 - cos(2(kx-\omega t))}{2}dt=\frac{1}{2}$

In short, why is the cosine expression evaluated to zero? Is it because the slopes "cancel out" each other, seeing as T is one period? Is there another way to evaluate the integral, without changing sine squared into the above mentioned expression?

Comment: The average **displacement** mentioned in your title is zero which is different from the (root) mean square value which you mention later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the proof that my high-school physics teacher showed me back in the day, before I had taken calculus:

- The averages $\langle \sin^2(x) \rangle$ and $\langle \cos^2(x)\rangle$ over one period are the same, because the sine function is just a phase-shifted cosine: $\sin(x) = \cos(x - \pi/2)$.
- But the average of the sum of these functions over one period is 1, because $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2 (x) = 1$.
- Since we have $\langle \sin^2(x) \rangle = \langle \cos^2(x)\rangle$ and $\langle \sin^2(x) + \cos^2 (x) \rangle = \langle \sin^2(x) \rangle +\langle \cos^2(x)\rangle = 1$, we conclude that $\langle \sin^2(x) \rangle = \langle \cos^2(x)\rangle = \frac12$.